# CPU at 35% when app is running

Tags: java, android, performance

So when I exit the android app with the home button and I check the CPU usage in the task manager it is using up around 35%  I am using:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

to gather the location of the user. I cannot imagine this is taking up 35% of the CPU though. The app is made up of Custom Listviews and swipea-able Fragment tabs so I cannot understand why it uses all of this cpu power when the app is not running in the foreground.

Comment: Keep in mind that the CPU speed is adjusted to the load on mobile devices. It might well be that you're using 35% of the CPU running at 1/10th of the maximum speed.

Comment: all other active apps are running around 1% though. So it doesnt make any sense to me and it is draining battery life

Comment: Have you used Android Debug Monitor to find the exact source of your leakage of CPU?

Comment: how would I go about that

Comment: You can see the code for the activity here: https://code.stypi.com/scpgmbc4  How can something this simple be causing such a huge leak